# Run PHPUnit for plugins folders from root directory

Tags: php, phpunit

I would like to run my PHPUnits tests in the plugins from the root directory.

The problem is that the individual plugins each come from their own repository and PHPUnit are registered there as via composer dev dependencies.

The build process for the main project "Application" pulls out the plugins using composer.

This structure has my current PHP project:

```
/Application
  /Plugins
    /PluginFirst 
        /tests
    /PluginSecond
        /tests
    /PluginThird
        /tests
```

Idea is to create shell or ruby script to iterate the plugins folder and run PHPUnit.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configuration file called phpunit.xml.dist and save it in your root project folder with the following configuration. Assuming you have also a test folder to run your own unit tests at the same level of the folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit>
     <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application API Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
            <directory>./Plugins/</directory>
        </testsuite>
     </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Then you can run phpunit in this way:

```
phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml.dist
```

If you want to exclude for example the PluginThird folder, you can add this line inside the  tag

```
<exclude>./Plugins/PluginThird/</exclude>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The Problem is the root project "Application" dont have the PHPUnit Dependency. (Which is so desired)
Each Plugin has his development PHPUnit Dependency.

Comment: The "Application" is production ready and will be deployed.
Therefore no PHPUnit Dependency on "Application".

Comment: What PHP framework did you use to build your Application?

Comment: We use WordPress and WPCLI, this structure is only a snippet.